# Spring Security - CSRF token on GET request

Tags: spring, spring-security

I configured CSRF protection in my Spring 5 (Boot 2) RESTful web service because I want to prevent CSRF attacks (I am using `JWT` cookie for authentication and authorization). On each request I am getting a new `XSRF` cookie. The value of that cookie I am sending back through the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header.

I noticed that `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods require the value of this token (in the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header) in order to work properly, but `GET` method works just fine without `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header.

Is this behavior intentional because `GET` method should not change state or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSRF token is intentionally excluded from GET to avoid token leakage to a 3rd party